# .Net HttpClient does not work with cookies

Tags: .net, vb.net, cookies

I am trying to log in the site and get the html body. This is my code:

```
Dim cookies = New Net.CookieContainer
Dim handler = New Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
handler.UseCookies = True
handler.CookieContainer = cookies
Dim client = New Net.Http.HttpClient(handler)
Dim pairs = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
pairs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("doLogin", "1"))
pairs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("login", "admin"))
pairs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("password", "qwerty"))
Dim content = New Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)
Dim request = New Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
request.Method = Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post
request.RequestUri = New Uri("http://example.com")
request.Content = content
Dim response = client.SendAsync(request).Result
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:/test.html", response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result, False)
```

But html page says that cookies are not enabled:

> Cookies are not found, please enable cookies

What can I do?

Comment: This suggests that the web server was expecting to receive a cookie from the client (probably a session cookie) and you have sent none.

Comment: You probably need to do a Get first to request the page which will populate your cookie container, then you can Post back to it.